# Is there a way to workaround a #define introduced by a vendor?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

So, a vendor that we use has provided a library (primarily for C, with some C++ support) that does the following:

```
#ifndef int64_t
#define int64_t s_int64
#endif
#ifndef int32_t
#define int32_t s_int32
#endif
#ifndef int16_t
#define int16_t s_int16
#endif
#ifndef int8_t
#define int8_t  s_int8
#endif
```

In one of their headers deep inside their library. Now the problem is that once their library is included in simple C++11 code such as:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vendor/library.h>

int main(void)
{
  std::int32_t std_i = 0;
  return std_i;
}
```

There is immediately a compiler error, (`s_int32` is not in `std::`). So question is, short of nagging the vendor to this fix this, is there anyway to workaround this in our code? (btw. things that I have tried, `#include <cstdint>` *before* their headers, no luck; `extern "C"` wrapper, no luck. The headers are installed in `/usr/include/` so no control over order of inclusion I guess as well...)

Comment: Don't include such headers in your code. They pollute it. Don't use the vendor's code.

Comment: @DanielDaranas, not an option if their library has to be used to access hardware! :/

Comment: You *can* use the library WITHOUT using the headers. Library is included by linker, the header is parsed by preprocessor; simply copy the header, edit it, include the local copy. It's C after all, not Java!

Comment: @vaxquis, sorry, but that's a really dumb suggestion, so I have to patch and maintain vendor header files as they change things? What a waste of time...

Comment: I'm not saying you *should* do it, I'm saying it's obviously *possible*. Daniel Daranas provided a valid point; you stated "it's not an option" providing invalid reasons, I provided an option, proving your reasons wrong; you plainly don't understand that you can't make your code vendor-dependent and portable at the same time. Your problem is mostly that you don't get that by accepting vendor's solution you basically agree to its programming contract; creating workarounds around this contact is a sign you don't agree to it - yet you use it while not try to create a better one.

Comment: btw, if you're talking about dumb wastes of time - using a library with invalid (non standards-conformant and error-producing) headers with no real attempt to improve the libraries/headers themselves is one; any reasonable person would just build a simple diff-based patcher for the header and include it into the build script. The patcher would simply create a local copy of the header, grep for offending lines and remove them. What is also dumb - assuming, in the era of information, "I have to patch and maintain vendor header files as they change things? What a waste of time.."

Comment: (or you could simply, in this particular case, undef those defs - but you said "it's ugly", not understanding that the inclusion of broken headers is what really is ugly here). But yeah, it's all obviously just a bunch of very dumb answers and suggestions made by trolls - since you're the only one with any real knowledge of CS and IT here.

Comment: @vaxquis, take a chill pill dude, and relax. If it were dumb answers, I would not have accepted any of them - and folks will not have upvoted them. If you think your answer is valid, please by all means submit it and let the community decide. It's not *dumb* to use a vendor library - it's what *must* be done when working with specific hardware. If this is what you do with your vendor libraries, then good luck to you.

Comment: Even more - since you by yourself obtained the updated headers from the vendor, you obviously *found the correct solution to the problem* - because you can't solve a psychological problem (desire to use broken vendor headers and conform to its spec with no errors appearing & without actually breaking the vendor's library implementation) with a CS solution; and, if you'd actually read what I wrote, *that's what I said*. By the way, consider the fact the answers got about 10x more votes than your question... The common ratio for good questions is 1x-2x. Do the math by yourself this time.

Comment: @vaxquis, okay you are entitled to your opinion as I am to mine. Yours is that I'm an expert troll with psychological problems and a severe reading disability. Fine, let's leave it at that. Bye.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48407/discussion-between-vaxquis-and-nim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing what else is in the file it's tricky to find a solution that would work 100%.

However, one idea that you could try would be the following (note - I've tried this vaguelly in my compiler, but I make no guarantees that it'll work in any other one).

Create a file containing their defines, but as typedefs:

```
typedef s_int64 int64_t;
...
```

Then some compilers allow you to specify a file to include before any others on the command line... for example, gcc has the `-include` switch, so you specify to include this file.

Then, also on your command line, you can make defines that map to themselves:

```
-Dint64_t=int64_t
```

or even put the defines in the above file:

```
#define int64_t int64_t
```

The result is, in theory, the `#defines` won't interfere with any other code (they *shouldn't* do anything - tho' I'm not sure if you could end up with recursive expansion?).  And as you've created a `typedef` to the correct type, the vendors code *should* still work.

The reason you put the typedefs into a file that's force-included, is that you want to ensure it gets included before anything else.

Then you should badger the vendor to update their code to use `typedef`.  You're a customer, they want to sell you a product.

All theory mind.

Comment: Actually, your point on the defines on the compilation line actually may do the trick! The problem we have is that we have several older releases of our code which include this libary that the vendor provides. We cannot re-release those older versions, however we can change the compilation line, this hack may work for the moment and allow us to use the newer release of the library..

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, adding a whole series of `-D...` to the compilation line fixes the compiler errors. This means both our older releases and any new compilations work okay... As a result, I will accept this answer...

Answer (score 21):

You can undefine their definitions.

```
#undef int64_t
#undef int32_t
#undef int16_t
#undef int8_t
```

Comment: ...eugh... horrible, but no choice... :/

Comment: @Nim it is. Macroses are almost always horrible.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem they are not. In plain ol' C it's necessary evil.

Comment: @Elias: these ones certainly aren't great, that's why the questioner is having a problem with them.

Comment: One thing to watch out for when undefining unfortunate macros, though, is that the vendor header might contain macros that (a) you use, and (b) need these macros to be defined the unfortunate way the vendor defined them. Hopefully not in this case, since the vendor header allows for someone else to define them, so probably doesn't rely on them being `s_int64` etc.

Comment: @SteveJessop: In this case, they're not great, true. But when it comes to bitwise constants (1,2,4...) or (`ARG_TYPE_A`, `ARG_TYPE_B`) is just so much more readable. Besides: I don't always approve of a compiler pretending to be smarter than me, when deciding _not_ to inline a function... the preprocessor doesn't think for you. But again: these macro's aren't great...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: One might argue that macros for named integral constants aren't great either, you could/should use an enum. Macros are like belief in magic, you use them to deal with anything you can't (yet) deal with properly ;-)

Comment: You can ease the undef pain a bit by making your own header file : `myVendor.h` which looks like : `#include "vendor.h" #undef int64_t #undef int32_t, etc...`

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor has a clever property: Recursion while replacing macros is prevented! Hence you can define them this way:

```
#define int64_t int64_t
#define int32_t int32_t
#define int16_t int16_t
#define int8_t int8_t
```

**before** including the vendor's header. That way they won't be redefined (as they are using `#ifndef`) and they keep their intended meaning for the rest of your code.

Comment: The only issue here is if the vendor's header assumes that `int64_t` is actually their own `s_int64`. Depending on what `s_int64` actually is, it could end up not mapping to the correct type when making calls to their library function. It's likely just a name, but you never know :)

Comment: @icabod If they really assume that, they should not have used `#ifndef`. But OK, I was just pointing out an option, only you can decide if it fits your environment.

Comment: Indeed, the only real solution is to get the vendor to fix their stuff - vote with your wallet :)

Comment: @icabod, unfortunately it's an OS release of their Enterprise product, thankfully, their service desk is superb, have just received a patch for the headers which fixes this - I guess lots of other customers moaned too... :D Now the problem I have is which answer to accept... Because all three (with votes) have contributed parts of the solution.. :)

Comment: I would suggest accepting this answer, as it's closer to what you're actually doing to solve the problem, albeit via the commandline rather than in source - my own answer added stuff that you probably don't need.  Look at me, throwing away rep!

Answer (score 0):

they are using `#ifndef` macro which means : *if not defined, then the value is ...*

Just define it first with your values :

```
#define int64_t (xx)
#define int32_t (xx)
#define int16_t (xx)
#define int8_t  (xx)
```

Comment: the problem is that those are supposed to be *types*, not defined constants. It's like saying `#ifndef int`.

Comment: I doubt that these own macros would be so much more useful than the vendor-defined ones.

Comment: how about `#define int64_t int64_t` ? and similarly for each type? then they would be defined to be themselves, everything should work...

Comment: Although it's technically undefined behaviour to `#define` a reserved name, `#define int64_t int64_t` will almost certainly make everything work. Assuming that your implementation does provide `int64_t`, of course, and you include "stdint.h".