# Can I mimic a C header that redefines bool in C++?

Tags: c++, c, typedef, mixing

I am writing a program and I would really prefer to write in C++, however, I'm required to include a C header that redefines bool:

```
# define false 0
# define true  1
typedef int bool;
```

The obvious solution would be to edit the header to say:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
# define false 0
# define true  1
typedef int bool;
#endif
```

but, alas, since the library is read-only I cannot.

Is there a way I can tell gcc to ignore this typedef? Or, can I write most functions in C++ and then make a C wrapper for the two? Or, should I suck it up and write the thing in C?

Comment: If that's `<stdbool.h>`, you can just `#define` the appropriate tag it has to say it's already done its work. If it's like C, `__bool_true_false_are_defined`

Comment: @chris `<stdbool.h>` should have its own c++ guards already

Comment: May be this will have something useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377678/is-there-a-way-to-workaround-a-define-introduced-by-a-vendor

Comment: @Erbureth, But you wouldn't want it happening even once.

Comment: @chris I meant c++ guards, not standard include guards

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can hack it!

The library, call it `fooLib`, thinks it's using some type `bool` which it has the prerogative to define. To the library, `bool` is just an identifier.

So, you can just force it to use another identifier instead:

```
#define bool fooLib_bool
#include "fooLib.h"
#undef bool
#undef true
#undef false
```

Now the compiler sees the offending line transformed to this:

```
typedef int fooLib_bool;
```

You're stuck with the interface using type `fooLib_bool = int` instead of a real `bool`, but that's impossible to work around, as the code might in fact rely on the properties of `int`, and library binary would have been compiled with such an assumption baked in.

Comment: That might not be a problem, as the library binary will see int anyway and you will need to provide an in at the interface level (or bool will be casted to it)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `#define <keyword> ...` is forbidden. I suppose most C++ compilers will accept it, but they would be within their rights to refuse to compile the program.

Comment: @MatthieuM., [Only if you include a standard library header.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726204/c-preprocessor-define-ing-a-keyword-is-it-standards-conforming) I'm not too sure how that would apply if the macro's there and gone all *before* any headers are included.

Comment: @chris: I hate the C++ Standard. Seriously. I've never read any other document with such intricate definitions and rules. Everytime you find a hard set rule (finally!), it's mitigated by some wording somewhere else. *sigh*

Comment: @MatthieuM., I can agree to that. It certainly makes it interesting. I have a feeling its complexity could be comparable to the laws we live by.

Comment: @chris: Of course, you may have a problem if the library header includes standard libraries....

Comment: @Hurkyl The library header is guaranteed to be C-only, and although the C standard library headers are tangentially referenced in the C++ spec, I think the intent is that the C-language rules should apply to them.

Answer (score 27):

I suppose you can wrap the offending code into a header and then undef what you don't need

Library_wrapper.h:

```
#define bool something_else // This will get you past the C++ compilation
#include "library.h"
#undef false
#undef true
#undef bool
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Library_wrapper.h" 
#include "boost.h"
```

Regarding the typedef.. the compiler should complain if you try to redefine a basic type in C++. You can redeclare a type by the way (it is allowed in C++) or define it (simple text replacement).

Comment: Prolly the typedef and not the #defines that's problematic.

Comment: In C++ you can redefine typedefs, in C you can't so I suppose a workaround as the above would be needed

Comment: I commented on your original post which didn't include your edit modifying the typedef.

Comment: -1, `typedef int int;` is *not* legal. Where did you even get that? It's an invalid combination of type specifiers and no declarator. It doesn't even appear to be a solution,  but just duplicates the problem at hand, which is the similarly invalid construct `typedef int bool;`.

Comment: "In C++ you can redefine typedefs" — you are allowed to repeat a `typedef` declaration, not to change the meaning. They behave as declarations, not definitions, and it's analogous to declaring a function prototype twice. "C you can't" — the rules are the same in C.

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately, no, you cannot use this file in Standard C++:

> **§7.1.3 [dcl.typedef]**
>
> **6/** In a given scope, a typedef specifier shall not be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to a different type.

Thus `typedef ... bool;` is forbidden.

> **§17.6.4.3.1 [macro.names]**
>
> **2/** A translation unit shall not `#define` or `#undef` names lexically identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 3, or to the attribute-tokens described in 7.6.

And in **§2.12 [lex.key]** we find that `bool` is a keyword.

Thus trying to trick the compiler by using `#define bool ...` prior to including the offending file is forbidden.

---

So, what is the alternative ? A shim !

Isolate that offending library behind a C & C++ compatible header of your own; and compile this part as C. Then you can include your own header in the C++ program without issue or tricks.

*Note: yes, most compilers will probably accept `#define bool ...`, but it is still explicitly forbidden by the Standard.*

Comment: Note: it has been ported to my attention that **[macro.names]** apparently only applies if you include a Standard Library header within the translation unit.

Answer (score 11):

You may copy a bad header and use an edited copy. Tell to compiler the path it should prefer and...

Comment: Or, just be sure to include the edited copy before the C library and the header guards will take care of the rest. +1

Comment: Oh… but note that the "patched" header may lead to ABI incompatibility with a library. You shouldn't patch the header unless you can recompile the library afterward, or if compilation isn't necessary.

Answer (score 8):

You could compile the code which uses the header as C, then just link it together with your C++ object files. You probably use MSVC or GCC; both can compile code as either C++ or C, and will allow you to create compatible object files.

Whether that's a clean solution or unnecessary overkill really depends on the exact situation.